# Updating the parent via rally API

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, rally

I have more than 1000 projects which are in closed state under one of our work space.

I got that data from - `https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/subscription?fetch=Workspaces,Name,Projects,State`

We want to update the "Parent" for the projects which are marked as "Closed".

```
import sys
from pyral import Rally, rallyWorkset
options = [arg for arg in sys.argv[1:] if arg.startswith('--')]
args    = [arg for arg in sys.argv[1:] if arg not in options]
server = <server>
apikey = <api_key>
workspace = <workspace>
project = <project_name>
rally = Rally(server,apikey=apikey, workspace=workspace, project=project)
rally.enableLogging('mypyral.log')
```

Method to check the status of the projects -

```
projects = rally.getProjects(workspace=workspace)
for proj in projects:
    print ("    %12.12s  %s  %s" % (proj.oid, proj.Name, proj.State))
```

I didnt find any reference to update the project parent here - Rest API `post` method - http://pyral.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interface.html?highlight=post

Comment: What language?  There are toolkits for node, java, .net and more.  It should be a fairly easy script- do the query to find all the closed projects, loop over each one and set its parent to the new project.  If you can post some code showing your progress we can probably be of more assistance...

Comment: @KyleMorse - I am trying it in Python, but we are flexible to make it work in any language like ruby OR nodejs. As of now I have the list of projects I want to move to different parent. I am looking for API method which can do this for a single project.

Comment: I think you can add to the Children collection of a project 25 items at a time.  That would reduce your # of calls quite a bit.  I'm not sure if the python or ruby toolkits support that or not.  node definitely does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in the following way:

```
#get object for 'New Parent':
```

target_project = rally.getProject('NewParentForClosedProjects')

projects = rally.getProjects(workspace=workspace)
    for proj in projects:

```
    #get children of project
    children = proj.Children

    for child in children:

        #if project closed:
        if child.State == 'Closed':
            #Then update Parent to new one:
            project_fields = {
                "ObjectID": child.oid,
                "Parent": target_project.ref
            }
            try:
                result = rally.update('Project', project_fields)
                print "Project %s has been successfully updated with new %s parent" % (str(child.Name), str(child.Parent))
            except RallyRESTException, ex:
                print "Update failure for Project %s" % (str(child.Name))
                print ex
```